# Rust modules, combine two use statements

Tags: rust

From documentation

```
use std::io;
use std::io::Write;
```

Two use statements where one is a subpath of the other

The common part of these two paths is std::io, and that’s the complete first path. To merge these two paths into one use statement, we can use self in the nested path, as shown in Listing

```
use std::io::{self, Write};
```

Combining the paths into one use statement

This line brings `std::io` and `std::io::Write` into scope.

if i brought `std::io` in the scope, isn't it obvious that `io::Write` will be available automatically in the scope provided Write is a public item? Why it needs to be imported separately?

Comment: Are you asking why `use std::io` does not recursively bring all items within, or why it does not automatically bring traits to scope so that their methods can be called? In either case, the answer will likely end up being a design decision.

Comment: As a an example to @E_net4iscleaningup  comment, There could be a lot of name conflicts with a components of `std::io`. Let's say you imported `std::io` to use `io::Result` in your code, this means you cannot define any trait or struct named as `Write` or `Read` or anything accessible inside `std::io`

Comment: Also Type Checker would work a lot more on that case, consider all the components inside `std::io` is visible on that file. This means it could compile slow, or it could check your code slowly, as a result your IDE also would not perform good. But this doesn't mean it is forbidden in Rust you can still do by importing like this `use std::io::*`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well your question, I think you're misunderstanding the `use` statements.

It seems to me that you're thinking the statement `use std::io` is going to bring all public stuff from inside it. But that's not the truth. It's just going to create an `alias` for `std::io` as just `io`, so you can use it as in `io::Result` or `io::Write`.  If you want to bring all public stuff from that, you should use `std::io::*` instead, but that's not recommended, as it's going to pollute your namespace.